# Polymer: Calling elements property in main app page from one of its views

Tags: javascript, polymer

Im using polymer starter kit, and in my main page (my-app) i have a div element which is hidden, and which i want to display on click from one of the apps views. I used syntax this.$.elementId.style="display: block;" but it returns error element is not defined. Is there any way to reach this value from one of its views?

Comment: Why not use [`dom-if`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if) for this? Regardless, you need to edit your question to include your actual element code, since that's the only way we can figure out *why* it's undefined.

Comment: It always returns an error when i try to include my code in my post :(

Comment: Is the div element you want to toggle and the element you click on to toggle the div in the same component?

Comment: No, div which i want to display is in my-app element and button on which i want to trigger it is in my-view1 element

Comment: Okay, that's why it's not working. In order for this.$.elementId syntax to work, the method at which includes this.$.elementId and the element with "elementId" has to be in the same component.

Comment: Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, but we can't help you without seeing your code. To add it to your post, click on "edit", then paste the code into the answer, then highlight the code and click on the `{}` button to turn it into a code block.

Comment: Ok, I will post it later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which version of polymer you are using, but this is the polymer 2.0 way of doing this. In order for an child element to communicate to the parent element, you need to use events. You need to dispatch an event within the view element and listen to the event in my-app element like this:

view element method

```
buttonClicked() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('button-clicked'))
}
```

my-app element

```
<my-view on-button-clicked="hideDiv"></my-view>
```

my-app element method

```
hideDiv() {
    this.$.elementId.style.display = "hidden"
}
```

Comment: Did it work? If it did, accepting the answer would be helpful

Comment: Accepting my answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Do you see a check mark under the "3" of my answer? click that!